# Nuxt.js generate page with dynamic URL

Tags: nuxt.js, generate, dynamic-url, content-pages

My nuxtjs app contains page with dynamic url (actually page has two params `event-slug` and `event-id`), then in that page's `asyncData` method, I extract these params from URL and use for `axios` request. This page opens when I click on one item on list of events (on another `events-list` page). When I trigger `nuxt generate` command, I encounter error because these params are not available while generating static pages. 
Is there any solution?

**SOLUTION (in case someone needs it later):**

Assume that I have `/event/:slug/:id` dynamic route in my Nuxt app and need to create route for all events I receive from backend, add this code into `nuxt.config.js`:

```js
 generate: {
    routes: () => {
 axios.get('endpoint to get list of events')
        .then((response) => {
          // assume we received array of events in response.data
          let events = response.data;
          return events.map((event) => {
          
            // assume that my Nuxt dynamic route is /event/:slug/:id
            return `/event/${event.slug}/${event.id}`
          })
        })
    }
  },
```

Comment: nuxt generate dynamic pages - Google search. If you want to generate routes with dynamic params, you need to set an array of dynamic routes.

Comment: What if list of events changes after nuxt application is loaded? From my understanding, it is not possible to reload nuxt config in runtime.

Comment: @Andis this is my understanding too.